# python peewee upsert only dictionary specified fields

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I am new to peewee (`v3.17`) - using with sqlite(`v3.40`), trying to write a function that updates or inserts a data to my user table,
This is the model class

```py
class MyUser(Model):
    id = AutoField()
    user_mail = TextField(unique=True)
    username_a = TextField(null=True)
    user_id_a = TextField(null=True)
    username_b = TextField(null=True)
    user_id_b = TextField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        table_name = 'my_user'
        database = db
```

This is the function I am using to add or update my data. [Refernce](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#upsert)

```py
def upsert_user(**user_data):
    """Insert / update given data to user table"""

    return (MyUser
            .insert(**user_data)
            .on_conflict(
                conflict_target=[MyUser.user_mail],
                preserve=[MyUser.username_a,
                            MyUser.user_id_a,
                            MyUser.username_b,
                            MyUser.user_id_b])
            .execute())
```

These are my sample data.

```py
data0 = {
    "user_mail": "user1@test.com",
    "username_a": "user1_a",
    "user_id_a": "a1",
    "username_b": "user1_b",
    "user_id_b": "b1"
}

upsert_user(**data0)

data1 = {
    "user_mail": "user1@test.com",
    "username_a": "user1_a_new",
    "user_id_a": "a1_new"
}

upsert_user(**data1)
```

**Expected only `username_a` and `user_id_a` columns to get updated preserving other columns,
but other columns got null(the default value) after function call.**

I've added all other column names to `preserve` because I need also these to work,

```py
data2 = {
    "user_mail": "user1@test.com",
    "username_b": "user1_b_new",
    "user_id_b": "b1_new"
}

# only update the mentioned colums

data3 = {
    "user_mail": "user2@test.com",
    "username_a": "user2_a",
    "user_id_a": "a2"
}

# Add new row
```

**How can I achieve update/insert only the mentioned dictionary columns.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `preserve` then, you want `update`, e.g.:

```
def upsert_user(**user_data):
    """Insert / update given data to user table"""

    return (MyUser
            .insert(**user_data)
            .on_conflict(
                conflict_target=[MyUser.user_mail],
                update=user_data)
            .execute())
```

Comment: Got it, perceived it incorrectly from the docs, I think the preserve syntax is to keep the values from the insert query in the table, and the update syntax is to change selected columns with new values..
However, I think the update, upsert, and on_conflict parts need some more clarification in docs. Maybe I can contribute..

Comment: I will work on getting this cleaned-up, I agree it is quite confusing.

Comment: The documentation is overall well elaborated, covers many best practices, I wish I had used this tool earlier, many struggling days thinking proper connection closing, multiline SQL queries, input sanitization...thought an ORM was overkill for small projects. This tool is a great saver, I really appreciate your work.